# Javadoc for method of anonymous object

Tags: java, methods, javadoc, anonymous-class

What is the best way to properly and usefully document a function of an anonymous object? I am doing some programming with Soar (API [here](http://winter.eecs.umich.edu/~jzxu/sml/index.html)), and have code that looks something like this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @return handler that does blah
 */
public static RhsFunctionInterface functionBlah() {
    return new Kernel.RhsFunctionInterface() {
        /**
         * Does blah
         */
        @Override
        public String rhsFunctionHandler(int eventID, Object data,
                String agentName, String functionName, String arguments) {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

When it is important to know what the function of the returned object does, what it expects for parameters, etc., I'm not sure what to write down. Eclipse seems to ignore the javadoc's method, and I really don't want to write separate classes for each of the handlers just for documentation purposes.

Comment: Who is the intended audience of your communication? If it is outsiders, then the method should not need any documentation as explained by http://stackoverflow.com/a/8797414/348975.  If it is insiders then they can read the source code directly.

Comment: Hmmmm, that is true emroy. The java.lang.Runnable that I'm instantiating anonymously shouldn't, in theory, be of interest to developers calling the enclosing method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method should not need any documentation at all, as it's the implementation of an interface, and that interface should be documented. The implementation of an interface behaves according to that.

Comment: This particular interface is used for generic handlers; the handlers can do anything the programmer would like.

Comment: @NateGlenn in that case, the best place for JavaDoc comments would be in the functionBlah method.  Users of this method should not need to know about or care whether or not you implemented the method using an anonymous class.

Comment: +1 - if the class needs javadoc comments it shouldn't be an anonymous class.

Comment: I disagree. What if the inner class is a `java.lang.Runnable` (which would be quite common)? I personally would want to know at a high level what the Thread does, and why it is a separate thread. Reading the javadoc at Oracle.com won't tell you the answer to that.